# How to check attribute change and trigger a callback in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to send an email notification when the email address is changed. To do that i need to detect first if the attribute actually changed. I think the best place to add the code is in an `after_filter` in the controller.

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
after_filter :email_change_notification, only: [:update]

def email_change_notification
  UserMailer.notify_new_email if @user.email_changed?
end
```

My problem now is that email `email_changed?` does not return expected value when used in this context. It is always `false`. As an alternative, I can do it in the model `after_save`

```
# app/models/user.rb
after_save :email_change_notification

def email_change_notification
  UserMailer.notify_new_email if email_changed?
end
```

This works but I think the former is a better approach since calling a mailer is not part of the model's responsibility.

My question would be:

(1) Where should I put such a callback (model or controller)?

(2) Is there a better way to make the controller approach work?

(3) Is there a better approach than the ones mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you may want to implement is an ActiveRecord::Observer

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html

This is designed exactly for your requiements... a class that performs trigger-like behavour on changes to the original class, but outside the class.

Very easy to set up and use!